# Drupal 8 include part template

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I'm trying to use Drupal 8, with an own theme, due big structure differences for my requirements I have a page--front.twig.html and a page.twig.html, I would like to create template parts as used in phrozn oder in a normal Symfony2 project, for example a footer.html.twig and a header.html.twig. These templates are saved under a subdirectory /parts/

But wenn I call this templates as normal I just receive a string with the name of the template.

For example:

```
{# in page.html.twig or page--front.html.twig #}
{% include 'parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

Returns the file name as string:

```
parts/footer.html.twig
```

It's possible to do that with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's possible using the name of the template in the path

```
{% include '@mytheme/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

thanks to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141066/drupal-8-include-part-template

Answer (score 5):

You can include any part of your template files like this

```
{% include directory ~ '/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

or this

```
{% include '@mytheme/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

I strongly recommend you to create a reusable layout for pages that will give you greater flexibility when dealing with more pages and variants.

```
{# filename: page-layout.html.twig #}

{% block content%}
{{ page.content }}
{% endblock%}

{% block footer%}
{% include '@mytheme/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
{% endblock%}
```

So you can do something like this in another page

```
{# filename: page--front.html.twig #}
{% block footer%}
<div> I want to handle a different footer in here</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Finally, I found really helpful to dig into suggestions array and see what Drupal is trying to use.

Cheers.

Comment: the `directory ~` part of your reply is very useful, thank's

Answer (score 1):

Now that https://www.drupal.org/node/2291449 has been committed you can also do:

```
{% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: May you write an answer also for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141066/drupal-8-include-part-template, possibly more extensive?

Comment: @kiamlaluno sure .tnx

Comment: When i use something like this: {% include 'site-header.html.twig' %} twig throws me error "Twig_Error_Loader: Template "site-header.html.twig" is not defined"
it works with @themename/site-header.html.twig, but i find it ugly and phpstorm doesnt know how to resolve it