# inline css in Drupal 8

Tags: css, optimization, google-pagespeed, drupal-8

In order to make Google Page Speed score in green and our search ranking happy. We will need to have the above-the-fold css included in the head of our page template. 
This was possible in Drupal 7 where I got sites running nicely.

But things are changing in Drupal 8 for the better. What I basically want to do is this (I know it doesn't work).

In html.html.twig I want to insert this code into the

```
<style media="all">
  {% include '@mytheme/style/inline.css' %}
</style>
```

And then I expect it to look something like this in the front end.

```
<style media="all">
  html{background:#fff;color:#000;}body{margin:0;}...
</style>
```

Anyone have a solution for me? I do consider making Grunt output a inline.css.html.twig template instead of the inline.css but I fear that it might get ruined when being run though the twig engine!?

Thanks
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution seems to be giving a full path to the file from root of the site.

```
<style media="all">
  {% include directory ~ '/style/inline.css' ignore missing %}
</style>
```

Update: I found the solution here [Drupal 8 include part template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378936/drupal-8-include-part-template)